# Como mostrar classificação de um time usando php?

Tags: php

Estou trabalhando com um ranking com mais de 500 times, usando php. O ranking tem alteração diariamente, a cada jogo de qualquer time que consta nessa base. A dúvida é, como exibir a classificação de determinado clube em determinada data?

Por exemplo, se for filtrar pela posição do Time A em 08/08/2008, atualmente eu estou pegando TODOS os times, jogando em uma tabela, e ai sim pegando a sua classificação naquela data. Só que estou achando muito complexo, pois a cada requisição, uma tabela é montada com todos os times pra dai sim filtrar a classificação. Se eu aumentar minha base de dados para 2 mil times por exemplo, vou ter que montar uma classificação com 2 mil times por exemplo, pra depois exibir o resultado, oque causaria uma sobrecarga imensa. Para mostrar todos os outros resultados o procedimento é muito simples, mas estou com dificuldade de mostrar a classificação na data.

Como posso implementar isso de uma forma mais simplificada?

Comment: Qual a base de dados?

Comment: Um MER do seu banco seria útil